# How to install Eclipse SDK Examples via Update Manager?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Documentation is irrelevant: nothing goes like written. [It is said](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/samples/samples.html), that there is Eclipse SDK Examples node in installation repository, but it isn't.

[image]

**UPDATE**

How to determine if specific example is installed and how to use it? For example, there is a "Field assist example" referred to in documentation. How to know if it is installed in my Eclipse? And if it is installed, then where it should be listed and how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like if you display the `Welcome` page (Help / Welcome) and select Samples there it will find the correct update site.

You can tell they are installed by looking at Help / About (or Eclipse / About on Macs) and clicking Installation Details. Eclipse SDK Samples should be in the list.

To use do File / New / Project and Code Samples should be in list of wizards.

Comment: Added installed check and use.